# Filtering the data in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am in new in angular 6. I am currently working on angular 6 project. I am coming into a situation where i need tho filer the data, but i have problem to keep the original object. Here is code:

```
    this.loginService.categoryType$.subscribe((data) => {
     for(var i=0; i<this.listPosts.length; i++){
       if(this.listPosts[i]['categoryName'] == data){

       }else{
         this.listPosts.splice(i,1);
       }

     }

   });
```

Html:

```
 <li class="nav-item" (click) = "selectedCategory('buy')"   style="cursor: pointer;">
              <a class="nav-link"  [ngClass]="{'active':selectedCat == 'buy'}">
              <i class="material-icons left-nav">
              shopping_cart
              </i>
              Buy
              </a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item" (click) = "selectedCategory('sell')"style="cursor: pointer;">
              <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active':selectedCat == 'sell'}">
              <i class="material-icons left-nav">
              shopping_basket
              </i>
              Sell
              </a>
           </li>
```

The problem is how to keep the original object value, because data is already spliced .

Comment: why do you not has two variables: data and dataFiltered?, dataFiltered=value?data.filter(x=>x.property==value):data

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the original list as well as a filtered one, I suggest you to save the original list in a variable, and then use rxjs methods to display the filtered

```
originalList$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
filteredList = [];

this.loginService.categoryType$.subscribe((data) => {
    this.originalList$.next(data);
});

this.originalList$.pipe(
map(data => yourLogicToFilter(data))
).subscribe(list => filteredList = list);
```

filteredList can be an Observable so you can use an async pipe in your code as well.

Probably there are even cleaner solutions embracing rxjs, but at least this should get you going on the logic

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to get the data and you do not want to mutate the original object stored in your component as a property. In which case, using splice defeats the purpose of what you are trying to do since it mutates the object.

There are a number of ways you could do this but I'll try to keep my answer as close to your code as possible. Correct me if I'm wrong but in my understanding, `this.loginService.categoryType$` is an observable or a subject for determining the category type. Since you already have the category type as an observable, you could use map on it and filter `this.listPosts` based on the category name.

```
    const listPosts$ = this.loginService.categoryType$.pipe(
       map(categoryType => this.listPosts.filter(
           listPost => listPost.categoryName === categoryType
       )),
    );
```

You could use `listPosts$` on your template and pipe async on it. 
`listPosts$ | async`

Or you could tap or subscribe against it like what you did to get the value and assign it to your component property or variable. I personally don't like this approach since you're storing the values from your stream in a variable.

```
    const listPosts$ = this.loginService.categoryType$.pipe(
       map(categoryType => this.listPosts.filter(
           listPost => listPost.categoryName === categoryType
       )),
    );

    listPosts$.subscribe(currentList => this.currentListPosts = currentList);
```

Hope this helps!